# Text is always black with any imported font in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, ui-toolkit

I'm using UI toolkit.
I have imported few different fonts, and set up a label. But when I assign custom font and font asset, changing text color becomes unresponsive and text is stuck on black.

There are no additional styles.

I tried - swapping different material in font asset to many different ones, nothing changes. Tried adding styling change in .uss, nothing changes.

[image]